# What are the different places on the map?

Tags: a-dark-room

I've noticed that the map has different types of landscape.  Does this play into the game at all?  I'm mostly concerned with combat in these places.  Are certain enemies only in specific areas?  Do some areas make you more likely to enter combat?

For example, when entering a location designated with a `.` the side-bar said:

```
the trees are gone. parched earth
and blowing dust are poor
replacements.
```

Logically, enemies would then be able to see you from greater distance, so chance of combat might go up?

When I went back into the `T` this message appeared:

```
a wall of gnarled trees rises from
the dust. their branches twist into
a skeletal canopy overhead.
```

The `,` says:

```
the trees yield to dry grass. the
yellowed brush rustles in the
wind.
```

Also, I assume `#` is some kind of path since I seem to not get attacked there

I saw [this wiki](http://adarkroom.wikia.com/wiki/A_Barren_World) but the only helpful info was:

```
O - A Deserted Town. The player can encounter a Thug, a Vigilante, a Beast, or
a Scavenger. The player may also encounter an Overturned Caravan or a Small
Cache of Supplies with a random assortment of rewards, a Small Basket of Food
with Cured Meat. Once conquered, the Deserted Town will turn into An Outpost.

P - An Outpost. A safe clearing that refills the player's water supply, and
provides the player with Cured Meats. Outposts can only be utilized once for
each journey out into the Barren World, but are replenished once the player
returns back to their village.
```

Comment: I think the only difference it makes is to the kind of enemies you might encounter. Not entirely sure though.

Comment: I don't want to spoil the game by giving a detailed answer but I'll say this, if you want to beat the game you have to venture out further. Each time you beat a site, like a deserted town or cave, it becomes an outpost connected to your village by a road. Slowly work your way out to the edge of the map from the center.

Comment: With the source now [made available](http://blog.doublespeakgames.com/?p=21) you could of course simply cheat and have a look...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Less than 10 blocks away from the village:

- In the forests (T), you can encounter Snarling Beasts
- On the fields(,), you can encounter Strange birds
- On barrens, (.), you can encounter Gaunt Men.

More than 10 but less than 20 blocks away from the village:

- In the forests (T), you can encounter Man-Eaters
- On the fields(,), you can encounter Huge Lizards
- On barrens, (.), you can encounter Shivering Men and Scavengers

More than 20 blocks away from the village:

- In the forests (T), you can encounter Feral Terrors
- On the fields(,), you can encounter Snipers
- On barrens, (.), you can encounter Soldiers

Looking at the source code, the three terrain types above do not effect the encounter rate. On paths, (#) you can never encounter battles. (thanks to Batophobia for reminding me)Also, the stealthy perk, which you can get from sparing the thief, lowers it.

Update: Looking at the code, I made a discovery! It appears that you can only get certain enemies on certain terrain at *certain distances from the village!*
Changed the list above to account for it.

Comment: I think certain terrains don't have encounters.  I've never had a battle when walking on a Path (#), an outpost (P), or the village (A).

Comment: True. I'll update the original post.

Answer (score 4):

```
VILLAGE: 'A',
    IRON_MINE: 'I',
    COAL_MINE: 'C',
    SULPHUR_MINE: 'S',
    FOREST: 'T',
    FIELD: ',',
    BARRENS: '.',
    ROAD: '#',
    HOUSE: 'H',
    CAVE: 'V',
    TOWN: 'O',
    CITY: 'Y',
    OUTPOST: 'P',
    SHIP: 'W',
    BOREHOLE: 'B',
    BATTLEFIELD: 'F',
    SWAMP: 'M
```

these are from the javascript

Comment: This is certainly helpful, but the main questions are `Are certain enemies only in specific areas?` and `Do some areas make you more likely to enter combat?`

Answer (score -3):

There are certain areas with different enemies. There isn't any areas THAT I KNOW OF (and i'm fairly new...) that make you more likely to enter combat. I think this answers your question. :)

Comment: Please try to be more specific with your answers and avoid speculation as much as possible.